# Rollback entire transaction in groovy.sql

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, transactions

I am a new bee to groovy and using groovy.sql to insert some data in to couple of tables as follows:

```
sql.cacheConnection {Connection connection - >
  connection.autoCommit = false
  try {
    def eventId = sql.firstrow("select eventId from event where...")
    if (eventId != null || eventId.size() != 0) {
      def qry = "Insert into table1 ... where eventId = :eventId"
      sql.execute(qry)
    }

    def meetId = sql.firstrow("select meetingId from meeting where...")
    if (meetId != null || meetId.size() != 0) {
      def qry2 = "Insert into table2 ... where meetingId = :meetingId"
      sql.execute(qry2)
    }

    // couple of inserts like this:
    // ....
  } catch (SQLException se) {
    println " Error: rolling back the transaction ---- " + se.getMessage()
    sql.rollback()
  }
  connection.autoCommit = true
}
```

My question here is, while processing data insert in the middle, If I disconnect the vpn connection, my script breaks and tables are partially updated.

But I really required to rollback the entire transaction if any connection loss happened like that, not to have partial data inserts. How to proceed entire rollback in this groovy sql?

Comment: what database/driver is this?  if you tell the database to not commit and then kill the connection, the db should not blindly commit unless it never supported transactions in the first place.

Comment: hi @cfrick , I m using my sql... 
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.26') 
do you have any idea?

Comment: is your storage engine innoDB?

Comment: yes its innoDB, any specific reason for this?

Comment: and the involved tables have it set? with e.g. myisam there simply is no support for transactions

Comment: yes cfrick, it is already set to innoDB.

Comment: Have you tried. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withTransaction(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: how to use that closure to rollback the entire transaction? pls help